# What is the quickest generic collection?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, collections

I have the following scenario. I have two collections, one has some items missing. What collection type would be the quickest to find the missing items and insert them?

Comment: You have two collections. One has some items missing. And the other has... what? Some good pie recipes? Major League Baseball scores? How does the other collection come into it? It looks like there is not enough information here to even begin to answer the question. Can you clarify the question?

Comment: Do you mean that one has items missing relative to the other?
so for instance
a = { a, b, c }
b = { a, c }
so list b has items missing relative to a?

Comment: The collections contains ints(userids), and the one is missing items relative to the other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HashSet is your friend:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx

Comment: Without knowing more, I don't believe you can say this. The performance of different colleciton types depends, amongst other things, on the number of items in them. Your HashSet will not outperform my List for a small number of items :)

Comment: For a small number of items the performance is not an issue. I dont think he's asking for a 10 item collection ;)

Comment: I have no information on the size of the collection; the OP didn't specify. The performance may not be an issue if you perform the operation once, but we don't know how often it is to be performed; it could be many times back-to-back. In fact, we know very little from the question, hence me being a but nit-picky about specific answers.

Comment: It's ok, the input is not as much as to start discussions on who is right :-D

Answer (score 2):

Clone the one without items missing.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to take a look into HashSet which has a method called [UnionWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342097.aspx).